# Problem with loading direct link - Vue single page app

Tags: vue.js, hyperlink, single-page-application

I have problem with Vue spa.
App work fine, when I go from some page to another.
App is e commerce and when I copy direct link of some product and send to someone I take to much time lo load that page, but when I click from list of product to specific product it load immediately.
Only direct link took too much time to load - like 10 sec.

I try remove some load function from page, but it's the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using lazy loading in your app? If not, Vue Router will try to load all pages when the site is first opened.

[You can see browser's console on network section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOwT5.png)

If you see that the files of all pages are loaded when the site is first opened, you are not using lazy loading.

That's all I can think of from the information you provided, I hope it helps.

[Vue Router Lazy Loading](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/lazy-loading.html#lazy-loading-routes)